# Invoking C# WPF code in C++

Tags: c#, c++, interop

thsi is my first time asking a question here, althought i use this site a lot!!

So after I've searched a while, i found this:
http://tigerang.blogspot.pt/2008/09/reverse-pinvoke.html

I think that is almost what i want to do. I will now explain:
(PLZ note i'm new to c++, c#, i come from java)I have a solution on visual studio with two projects, unmanaged c++ and a C# WPF app. The c++ only has one class, that does some processing using OpenCV. The WPF class connects to an image, retrieves some (x,y) points, and i have to pass them to c++. Afterwards I will call a C++ function from the WPF side, where i will get my results.

SO my question now is, I want to pass a List of Points (List), but i'm having trouble adapting the example I'm seeing to my situation and i found very litle documentation on this (or perhaps i'm too newbie and i don't know how to find/use it).

Sample code:
C#

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public struct Ponto
{
    public double x;
    public double y;
}


[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public delegate List<Ponto> CallBackDelegate();



public class ManagedClass
{
    private CallBackDelegate _delegate;



    public List<Ponto> vectorp;

    public ManagedClass()
    {
        _delegate = new CallBackDelegate(this.Foo);
    }

    public CallBackDelegate GetDelegate()
    {
        return _delegate;
    }

    public List<Ponto> Foo()
    {
       //do shit
        Ponto p1 = new Ponto();
        p1.x = 10;
        p1.y = 2;
        Ponto p2 = new Ponto();
        p2.x = 5;
        p2.y = 7;
        Ponto p3 = new Ponto();
        p3.x = 3;
        p3.y = 8;
        vectorp.Add(p1);
        vectorp.Add(p2);
        vectorp.Add(p3);


        return vectorp; 
    }
}
```

---

SAmple Code
C++;

```
 #include <iostream>

 #pragma once
 #include <windows.h>
 #include <list>


 #define INTEROPBRIDGE_API __declspec(dllexport)

 INTEROPBRIDGE_API void fnInteropBridge(list<Ponto> data) //IM GETTING ERRORS HERE
 {
     ManagedLib::ManagedClass^ c = gcnew ManagedLib::ManagedClass();
     IntPtr p = Marshal::GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(c->GetDelegate());

     NativeToManaged funcPointer = (NativeToManaged) p.ToPointer();

     // invoke the delegate
     funcPointer(data);
 }


 // data structure for the callback function
 struct Ponto
 {
     double x;
     double y;
 };

 // callback function prototype
 typedef void (*NativeToManaged)(list<Ponto> data);

 using namespace std;
 void main()
 {
   cout << "Hello World!" << endl;   
   cout << "Welcome to C++ Programming" << endl;

 }
```

Comment: I think you're overcomplicating it all too much. Why don't just use [this managed OpenCV wrapper](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) and stay 100% in the managed world?

Comment: Well, first because i already have some code written in C++. Second because i do a lot of image processing (30fps) and i read somewhere that c++ is faster processing images, althought you maybe be right, because the image processing is on the wpf side. Whats your opinion on this? Do you think that with nowadays pc's this will be an issue?

Comment: That depends on what you're doing with the images, but anyways the transition from managed to unmanaged is going to eat whatever performance gain you can get from c++. If you are really concerned about performance, stay in either managed or unmanaged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your C++ code won't work because System.Collections.Generic.List is completely different from C++'s std::list.

If your C++ code is managed (as it currently is), you can just reference the C# classes directly. No need for function pointers.

But if you really want to consume C# code from unmanaged C++, the simplest way is through COM. The only thing you need to change about your C# code is to change ManagedClass.Foo to return an array instead of a List, because List is not visible to COM, plus add a couple of attributes to the types and add an interface for the class to implement:

```
[ComVisible(true)]
[Guid("2EF06BCB-A25B-41AD-B233-33A956DBEB69")]
public struct Ponto
{
    public double x;
    public double y;

    public Ponto(double x, double y)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}

[ComVisible(true)]
[Guid("EB9258F5-DCFB-4F91-8342-5A05EB17557D")]
public interface IManagedClass
{
    Ponto[] Foo();
}

[ComVisible(true)]
[Guid("11B23AD7-F79E-45D7-BC87-89F0DBC8B83F")]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
public class ManagedClass : IManagedClass
{
    private List<Ponto> points;

    public ManagedClass()
    {
        points = new List<Ponto>();
        points.Add(new Ponto(1.0, 1.0));
        points.Add(new Ponto(2.0, 2.0));
        points.Add(new Ponto(3.0, 3.0));
    }

    public Ponto[] Foo()
    {
        return points.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Build the project, start the Visual Studio Command Prompt with administrator privileges, and use a command like this to export a type library for the assembly and register it:

> regasm ManagedAssembly.dll /tlb:ManagedAssembly.tlb /codebase

And the C++ code would consume it like this:

```
#import "ManagedAssembly.tlb"
#include <iostream>

using namespace ManagedAssembly;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ::CoInitialize(NULL);

    {
        IManagedClassPtr pManagedClass(__uuidof(ManagedClass));

        SAFEARRAY* psa = pManagedClass->Foo();
        Ponto* pPoints = (Ponto*)psa->pvData;

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
            cout << pPoints[i].x << " " << pPoints[i].y << endl;
    }

    ::CoUninitialize();
}
```

Comment: HI thanks for your reply!! I'm trying to do what you suggest, but when i oepn the command prompt in admin mode and enter the command you gave me, it gives me an error (unable to locate input assembly 'managedassembly.dll'). Am i putting a wrong name on the assembly ??

Comment: i think that ManagedAssembly is the name of my class, but i went through the output of the build files and the only dll's i can locate are specific to other classes from other projects that are present in my solution

Comment: Yes, you're supposed to replace ManagedAssembly.dll with the real name of your assembly. If your C# project is a .exe and not a DLL, then use the name of that .exe. But then, does that mean that it's the C++ project that's a DLL?

Comment: I don't understand that much about dll. I just created a c++ console aplication. I just have some code that uses opencv, it just returns points and int's, nothing else, is it better to create a dll for the c++? my c# project is a wpf aplication

Comment: It's possible to communicate between two .exes, but more often you want to do this using DLLs (one would be a .exe and the other a DLL) because what you have is one logical application. In your case it sounds like the C# project should be the .exe and the C++ project should be the DLL. To consume C++ code from C#, you have three options: C++/CLI, COM and P/Invoke. COM seems like the best fit here, but C++/CLI and P/Invoke are easier if you don't have much experience.

Comment: From my searchs I found about Reverse P/Invoke, that's what the link tlaks about. So i need to call a c# function from c++ and a c++function from c#. i'll try again using a dll project!! thanks for you help, if i ran into any troubles ill post here!!! many thanks

Comment: After i use regasm, when i do the #import "ManagedAssembly.tlb" it gives an error and says 'cannot open source file "c:\path\ManagedAssembly.tlh . am i missing something here?

Comment: That's probably an IntelliSense error, not a compiler error. Compile any file where ManagedAssembly.tlb is imported (or build the whole project), and the error should go away.

Comment: i tried, it gives me this error - emotionsdll.cpp(6): fatal error C1083: Cannot open type library file: 'FaceTrackingBasics-WPF.tlb': No such file or directory

Comment: Obviously the .tlb file needs to be in the same folder as the C++ file that imports it, or you can specify a full path in the import directive: `#import "C:\example\FaceTrackingBasics-WPF.tlb"`

Comment: that worked!! but now it cant find the namespace, i tried the name of the tlb file and the actual namespace name. any thoughs?

Comment: Open the .tlh file and see what it contains. It should be located in `<visual studio folder>\Projects\<C++ project>\<C++ project>\Debug` (notice the double `C++ project` folder).

Comment: its empty, and the tli file is empty too

Comment: btw, dont know if is relevant, but i have visual studio 2012 and 2010 installed, i could only find visual studio 2010 command line and i had to cd to the path where my .exe is located

Comment: Well that's not good :( Are you sure you used the attributes I showed: ComVisible, Guid and ClassInterface? All I can tell you is that I tested the code I posted and it built and executed fine.

Comment: well i have a class inside a class, maybe im putting your code on thw wrong place. im making a kinect app, this is the code of the class that i want to call from c++

Comment: Don't know what to tell you, the code seems fine. Maybe start another question about this specific problem, because probably no one else is reading this question at this point.